# Looking for a YA book about a boy that learns to use powers from an adept in a weird house that appears abandoned from the outside

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a YA book about a boy who learns to use powers from a mind-adept, in a seemingly abandoned house. The adept helps him open his mind by using a cube. One of his powers, I believe, is to go into dreams of people that  he knows. He helps his young female neighbor friend by doing this, opening a door in her mind. He tries to open the mind-door of a local older bully, but finds out the young man can't be helped because he has been abused mentally and physically. I don't believe the book I read is past 1995. It might have the word "adept" in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Christopher](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1159928.Christopher) by Richard M. Koff

> Christopher is 13 and often too smart for his own good. He hates
>   school and can’t seem to stay out of trouble. On a dare he knocks on a
>   door to a house all his friends say is haunted and meets a strange,
>   quiet man who calls himself the Headmaster.
>
> The Headmaster starts Christopher on a series of lessons unlike
>   anything he was taught in school. He learns how to move objects with
>   his mind alone, how to read other people’s thoughts, he becomes
>   invisible or shrinks to the size of a pencil.
>
> It’s not just for fun. The Headmaster has a mission for Christopher
>   that will change his life forever.

Comment: The cubes are mentioned at http://w1.loganberrybooks.com/stumpthebookseller/?p=5839