# YA fiction set in late 80's America about a boy and metal numbered cubes

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, psychic, psychology

I read this story in around 88-90.  I remember that it had a blue cover, and a boy with the head of a professor on it.

The story was about the boy who was having trouble at home and he meets a professor that gives him numbered metal cubes for homework, that when he squeezes them in the correct way, he gains a mental ability for 12 hours.

It eventually ends with him maturing to a point
and he becomes empathetic towards his family and starts helping out more around the house and no longer as self-absorbed.

Google has not been helpful with results.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a book you're asking about?

Comment: Yes. I should have made that more clear from the get.  It's a book about 150 pages long.

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps *[Christopher](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1159928.Christopher)* by Richard M. Koff as per [Looking for a YA book about a boy that learns to use powers from an adept in a weird house that appears abandoned from the outside](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231366/looking-for-a-ya-book-about-a-boy-that-learns-to-use-powers-from-an-adept-in-a-w)?

> Christopher is 13 and often too smart for his own good. He hates school and can’t seem to stay out of trouble. On a dare he knocks on a door to a house all his friends say is haunted and meets a strange, quiet man who calls himself the Headmaster.
>
> The Headmaster starts Christopher on a series of lessons unlike anything he was taught in school. He learns how to move objects with his mind alone, how to read other people’s thoughts, he becomes invisible or shrinks to the size of a pencil.
>
> It’s not just for fun. The Headmaster has a mission for Christopher that will change his life forever.

A review [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180706125653/http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-465997.html) mentions the blocks:

> The book is basically about a boy who bravely knocks on the door of a supposedly haunted house, wherein he meets "The Headmaster", a mysterious person who knows an awful lot about Christopher. Over the course of the book, he helps Christopher develop his mental abilities, with the aid of some little gold cubes with binary numbers on them (I still think of this book when I use binary).

The Amazon page for the book mentions one of the editions being 161 pages, which matches with you saying there were about 150 pages. There are a few covers with significant amounts of blue:

[image: Cover of 1981 edition of Christopher] [image: Cover of 2001 edition] [image: Cover of one of the Bantam Books editions]